# How to effectively check user rights on update actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'm getting started writing my own Action Filters and I have to say that this feature is quite nice. However I'm puzzled with a design question. When we have CRUD actions for let us say a product in a supermaket, the Action Methods looks like that :

```
public ActionResult CreateProduct(int ShopID); // Users within specific role for that shop
public ActionResult GetProduct(int ProductID); // Everybody can do
public ActionResult UpdateProduct(int ProductID); // Users within specific role for that shop
public ActionResultat DeleteProduct(int ProductID); //Users within specific role for that shop
```

My problem is that I don't have global roles in this app. Here roles are limited to a certain context : A user who is admin in shop A is probably not admin in Shop B. So here comes my problem. In my authorization filter, I can easily check the rights of the current user for the CreateProduct Action because the ID of the Shop is passed in parameter.

For the GetProduction Action, the problem begins to appear but it's quite manageable because everybody is supposed to have access to that Action. However for the Update and Delete actions, how can I know the rights of the current user since I don't know to which shop the product belongs ?

Well, the point is that my Filter is applied to Actions working on various repositories, not only with Products so I can't say "If the action name contains the word Update, retrieve the corresponding shop in the Products repository". So far I have imagined two solutions

1. Checking the name of the action in my filter and handling every case by hand. (Looks like a very bad solution to me)
2. Passing both the Product ID and the Shop ID as parameters to my Actions, but I don't feel like it's the normal way to go. I feel like I would introduce some kind of redundancy by doing so and I don't know if it's a common practice.

What is the way to go ? (Please, don't tell me to add 3 Layers and a factory pattern, I'm a Junior designer and I've spent the last month trying to get a state of the art design. Now it's quite decent but I really can't spend more time to change deeply the design again).

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need access to the particular business entity from your database to check this access, I don't think you can effectively do this as an action filter.

You may need some kind of '`IsUserInRoleForShop(role, shop)`' method that can be invoked from the methods that need to check it (seeing as these only seem to be a selection from your codebase.

You need to query the DB to get the shop ID (and I imagine you may need to do this anyway to properly update an entity within your model).  Passing the shop ID is a bad idea, as without validation, you then are open to somebody fiddling with the post to pass their shop ID and somebody elses product ID.

Comment: Thank you, I misread your answer actually. I've just edited that comment. So there is no way to move all the authorization logic out from the controller ?

Comment: And thank you for the info concerning the passing of the Shop ID in the URL !! It's very important to know, I didn't imagine that.

Comment: It's hard to remove it all, particularly when you are going to have different authorization rules depending on what you are going to access.  It the code that runs the authentication is common, then at least it's not all scattered through your codebase.